# Update div height calculated with js on window resize

Tags: javascript, resize, height, width

The code to make a div height equal to its width below:

```
$('div').height($('div').width());
```

However if you manually resize the browser window the height will not update - you need to refresh the page. Any idea how to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your code on the window.onresize event :

```
window.onresize=function(){
  $('div').height($('div').width());
};
```

The doc : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp